# htaccess & clean urls / not working after website moved to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

i had to move a website to a new subdomain. previously it was available at `www.some-domain.com`. it has now moved to `http://shop.some-domain.com`.

there are only some bits of the website which actually use clean urls, for example: `http://shop.some-domain.com/en-GB/shop/accessories/Soft-Scarf`

and exactly those URLs do not work anymore, i receive an error 404 when trying to open them. other parts of the website which do not use clean urls work fine.

the website files are located in the root folder (/)... the htaccess inside this folder looks like this:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.some-domain.com [NC]

# i think this line is causing the problem:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.some-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /webEdition/redirectSEOurls.php
```

tried changing the URL in the line to shop.some-domain.com but it didn't help

help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about the error source.  Just change the two occurrences of `www` to `shop`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shop\.some-domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shop.some-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The purpose of the `RewriteCond` line and subsequent `RewriteRule` was to force requests like `http://some-domain.com` to the canonical domain `http://www.some-domain.com`.  You've now changed that to `shop.some-domain.com` and so it's a simple matter of updating both the condition and the rewrite rule.